# Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 required to install Python package in virtualenv

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip, virtualenv

I was trying to install the bokeh Python package via pip but I was thrown this error:

```
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
```

I fixed that error by installing Microsoft Visual C+ and installed successfully after that.

However, now I want to install bokeh inside my virtual environment which I created with virtualenv. My intent is to build a Flask app.

I got the same error again, but this time I have no idea what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

for future google users / stack overflow users.

I had a similar error, but I needed Visual C++ 14.0.  This error popped up while trying to install a package while `venv` was running (with the `activate.bat` script already run)

apparently updating setup tools was the solution. And by that I mean, when I used pip to uninstall uninstalled [SoundCard](https://github.com/bastibe/SoundCard/blob/master/setup.py) and re-ran setup.py for SoundCard, I received no more errors about v14.0 missing. (This was all with `venv` running).

I already had `Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 v14.0` installed locally.  But my `venv` couldn't find it.

Run this command to update setuptools.

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

I updated from `28.8.0` to `41.1.0`  but the linked comment below says`36.2.7` worked for them.

If this worked for you, please give the comment below some love as well.

[Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/55575792#comment77948711_40888720)

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the MSVisual command prompt, and cd to your virtualenv directory. From there, try installing with pip.

You can also try updating pip, and setuptools in your virtualenv.

I fixed this problem, but I did quite a few things before I did, so I'm not quite sure how I fixed this part of it.