# How do I solve the problem of not being able to install the lxml and pandas package in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am currently learning beautiful soup with Pycharm. I was installing the library lxml and pandas, an error was shown that I need to install Visual C++ 14.0. However, even after I install the build tools, I was not able to include those libraries.

[LXML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fduN0.png)

If I use the command prompt, I was able to install both pandas and lxml. Therefore, I would like to learn from you guys, did I miss any steps in setting up the venv?

I tried the steps shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556169/microsoft-visual-c-10-0-required-to-install-python-package-in-virtualenv) with no luck.

Comment: Can you please post the error.

Comment: ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

Comment: Also, please post the command that produced the error. (Kindly edit the question)

Comment: Inside pycharm venv library 
"pip install lxml"

Comment: I Kinda figured it out, the problem was to update the setup tools. Thanks Ashwin.