# Error while installing lxml through pip: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip, lxml

I am on a windows 10 machine and recently moved from python 2.7 to 3.5. When trying to install lxml through pip, it stops and throws this error message-

> building 'lxml.etree' extension
>   error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

I have a working copy of VS 2015 installed. When I try to install the visual cpp tools through that link, it says that Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 is already installed on the machine. I also tried installing visual studio c++ 2015 redistributables, both 64 and 32 bit versions, but both of them say that there's another version of the product already installed. 
typing set in the command prompt includes this -

> VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\

Which means that the path is set. 
This is probably the only resource I could find on SO, but the answer suggests rolling back to Python 3.4.3 from 3.5. Has anybody resolved problems of this kind?

[Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)
EDIT: I managed to install it using the precompiled binary (Thanks Paul), but I would still like to know what's causing this.

Comment: get the precompiled binary for lxml. http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Comment: But that's just a workaround, right? I would also like to know why the error is coming up even though I have everything installed and the paths set up. I will, however, install the binary in case I can't find anything else, thanks!

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

I am also facing exact same thing while installing **mysqlclient**. Workaround or proper solution anything will do.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/55575792#55575792

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you checked that when you installed Visual Studio, you installed the C++ compiler? It seems like a silly question, but this is the mistake I made. Check by going into the setup for visual studio (Programs and features: Modify "Visual Studio 2015"), then under `Programming Languages->VC++`, make sure it's ticked.

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

Comment: I thought I must have had C++ installed and went through a few other solutions before giving up and trying this. Realized that when I originally installed Visual Studio it was for C# and the android emulator. I'd left C++ off to save disk space. So my $0.02 to others is not to dismiss this out of hand.

Answer (score 10):

1. Run `pip install wheel`
2. Download **lxml** from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml, if your python version is 3.5 , download `lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl`.
3. Run `python -m pip install lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl`

Comment: I think this is the better solution which avoids to install visual studio if you don't need it.

Answer (score 6):

As an update to the answer from @davidsheldon above, if you want to use Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 instead of 2015, it will work.

I found that the default install of the build tools stand alone was not enough, however, I added `VC++ 2015.3 ... toolset for desktop (x86,x64) and then python was happy:

[image: Screenshot showing the installation screen for Visual Studio 2017]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, that was very helpful! In Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools, the package is called "MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)"

Answer (score 2):

I've found another solution to get through this:
Because I use anaconda python, so I use this code:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same question with you! I found a way no need install vs2015,maybe,you just haven't install twisted.http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted .download twisted --version（Twisted‑17.5.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl）(maybe win_amd32.whl if 64didn't work)，and run : pip PATH + filename

```
pip install C:\Users\CR\Downloads\Twisted-17.5.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

pip install Scrapy
```

I just install successful! good luck for you!

my step to insatll scrapy:
1.pip install wheel
2.pip install lxml
3.pip install pyOpenSSL
4.pip install Twisted (fault->do like above)
5.install pywin32 form : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/ 
6.pip Scrapy (succesful)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and noticed that I had installed the 32bit version in a 64bit machine. All I did was uninstall the wrong one and install the right version and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve this, can be automated as it doesn't require user input:

```
python -m pip install https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/archived/lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
```

This will install the 64-bit version on your machine.

Answer (score -2):

First:

```
pip install wheel
```

Second： go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml
and download proper wheel.

`pip install` the file you downloaded (.whl).