# Python: installing a module successfully but it is not available via import

Tags: python, module, pip, installation

I'm using Jupyter Notebook and I want to import an external toolbox called [bluepyopt](https://github.com/BlueBrain/BluePyOpt). As it currently only runs in Python 2.7, I set up a Python 2.7 Kernel as described [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html). So I can change my kernel to python 2 in Jupyter Notebook. 
If I want to import the module using

```
import bluepyopt as bpop
```

I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-83e46e18aae9> in <module>()
      3 
      4 # to create electrical cell models
----> 5 import bluepyopt as bpop
      6 import bluepyopt.ephys as ephys
      7 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bluepyopt'
```

I install *bluepyopt* the way I usually install modules with

```
!pip install bluepyopt
```

This also gives me an unsual super loooooong output. I don't know what is important here, so I will post all of it just to be sure. This only occurs in python 2.7 however, in python 3 everything works fine! Any idea why it is like that?

```
Collecting bluepyopt
Collecting efel>=2.11 (from bluepyopt)
  Using cached efel-2.12.11.tar.gz
Collecting ipyparallel (from bluepyopt)
  Using cached ipyparallel-6.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.8 in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare>=0.7.3 in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6 in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bluepyopt)
Collecting scoop>=0.7 (from bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.18 in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bluepyopt)
Collecting future (from bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: deap in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from efel>=2.11->bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4 in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipyparallel->bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipyparallel->bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipyparallel->bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=13 in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipyparallel->bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4 in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipyparallel->bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipyparallel->bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipyparallel->bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipyparallel->bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.8->bluepyopt)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.3.4 in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scoop>=0.7->bluepyopt)
Collecting argparse>=1.1 (from scoop>=0.7->bluepyopt)
  Using cached argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.18->bluepyopt)
Building wheels for collected packages: efel
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for efel: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for efel: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Alex\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-cygqwlch\\efel\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5k5lqwx6pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
  copying efel\api.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
  copying efel\io.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
  copying efel\settings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
  copying efel\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
  copying efel\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
  copying efel\DependencyV5.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\Utils.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\LibV1.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\LibV2.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\LibV3.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\LibV4.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\LibV5.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\FillFptrTable.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\DependencyTree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\efel.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\cfeature.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\Global.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\mapoperations.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\types.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  copying efel\cppcore\eFELLogger.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
  UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel/_version.py
  set build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel/_version.py to '2.12.11'
  running build_ext
  building 'efel.cppcore' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for efel
Failed to build efel
Installing collected packages: efel, ipyparallel, argparse, scoop, future, bluepyopt
  Running setup.py install for efel: started
    Running setup.py install for efel: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Alex\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-cygqwlch\\efel\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-n69ud86n-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
    copying efel\api.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
    copying efel\io.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
    copying efel\settings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
    copying efel\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
    copying efel\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
    copying efel\DependencyV5.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\Utils.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\LibV1.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\LibV2.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\LibV3.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\LibV4.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\LibV5.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\FillFptrTable.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\DependencyTree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\efel.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\cfeature.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\Global.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\mapoperations.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\types.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    copying efel\cppcore\eFELLogger.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel\cppcore
    UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel/_version.py
    set build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\efel/_version.py to '2.12.11'
    running build_ext
    building 'efel.cppcore' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for efel
Command "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Alex\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-cygqwlch\\efel\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-n69ud86n-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-cygqwlch\efel\
Requirement already satisfied: NEURON in c:\users\alex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

Some more maybe useful information when using the python 2 kernel in Jupyter Notebook:

```
In [1]:
import sys
sys.executable

Out [1]:
'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ipykernel_py2\\python.exe'  #kernel python 2.7
'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Anaconda3\\python.exe' #kernel python 3

In [2]:
from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_data_dir
print(jupyter_data_dir())

Out[2]:
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\jupyter

In[3]:
sys.path

Out[3]:
['',
 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ipykernel_py2\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ipykernel_py2\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ipykernel_py2\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ipykernel_py2\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ipykernel_py2\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ipykernel_py2',
 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ipykernel_py2\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ipykernel_py2\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\.ipython']

In[4]:
!jupyter kernelspec list

Out[4]:
Available kernels:
  python3    C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
  python2    C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels\python2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while installing lxml through pip: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949519/error-while-installing-lxml-through-pip-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Answer (score 2):

As i can see the module is not properly installed and giving dependency for Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0.

Try to install Microsoft Visual C++ build tools from this link http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Then try installing the module using pip again

```
pip install bluepyopt
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I installed Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable für Visual Studio 2017, which didn't change anything.

Comment: Don't install the visual studio build tool, install visual c++ 2015 build tools

Comment: That solved the issue for my python 3 kernel! Nice. But if I install it in my python 2.7 kernel, I get the same output and import error. Weird.

Comment: For Python 2.7 you need much older [MSVC compiler](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Which_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_compiler_to_use_with_a_specific_Python_version_.3F).

Comment: @SvennoNito vote up if the answer helped you thanks !

Comment: @phd do I just install both MSVC compilers on my computer then or do I need to make sure that each python version has access to the correct compiler? If so, how?

Comment: As both python points to different version of the compiler you need to install both