# Anywhere I can get webrtcvad pre-compiled for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to do some audio work in python, on my work computer. Getting IT approval to install anything is a laborious process, so I'm looking for a work around.

Anyways, the long 'n short of it is that when I run `pip install webrtcvad`, it fails, and tells me I need visual C++ 14. I have 2015, but apparently I need that specific version.

Is there anywhere I can download that package pre-built/compiled? I've been looking for the wheel file, but only found linux ones (I think, does that even matter? I'm on windows 10):

https://www.piwheels.hostedpi.com/simple/webrtcvad/

And I don't really know where to put one if it works, in any case. Traceback included for no real reason, just because I felt I should.

```
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for webrtcvad
  Running setup.py clean for webrtcvad
Failed to build webrtcvad
Installing collected packages: webrtcvad
  Running setup.py install for webrtcvad ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\ylwaller\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\sg2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ylwaller\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wx00j30u\\webrtcvad\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ylwaller\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0f_keevu\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    copying webrtcvad.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    running build_ext
    building '_webrtcvad' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Comment: You can use VC [2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40886619/7976758) or [2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671800/7976758)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Answer (score 0):

I found this (Works for Windows):

```
 pip install https://github.com/respeaker/respeaker_python_library/releases/download/v0.4.1/webrtcvad-2.0.9.dev0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

From: https://github.com/respeaker/respeaker_python_library

Hope its of any help.

Comment: Questions asking ( suggestion or promotion) of 3rd party dlls is offtopic - see  
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: My bad, I'll watch out for suggestion or promotion from now on.

Comment: I was unaware, thanks Emile. That one didn't work, I'll go looking for it on there though

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when installing the requirements.txt file in Pycharm IDE as part of a project. It was actually the issue with C++ compiler in my PC with windows 10. You can get the required build package from link https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
Select only the C++ build package and perform installation. This is a 1.7Gb file and takes some time to install. Once installed, it will prompt to restart your system and the installation will work fine for 'webrtcvad'