# Installing a package that require C++ on pycharm (windows) using pip

Tags: windows, pip, pycharm

I am developing a program in Python on Windows 10 using Pycharm. In this program I need to import [this Python package](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/) that uses pip to be installed.

Following [the standard procedure to install with pip on Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) I get an error:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

The url gets me to an abandoned website but I finally found a way to install Visual C++ building tools ([there](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/visual-cpp-build-tools/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2F)).

Unfortunately I still have the same error.

I also upgraded the pip version to 18.1, in case the outdated version was to blame, but it didn't change anything.

What do I need to do for Pycharm to recognize my installation of Visual C++?

EDIT: This question is not the same as other questions that don't involve using Pycharm. Please take this into consideration while answering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip error even Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610212/pip-error-even-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-installed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949519/error-while-installing-lxml-through-pip-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required

Comment: @phd difference with the potential duplicate is that I want to install it through an IDE (Pycharm) and I correctly installed building tools and not redistributable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to use pip, there is very sophisticated way to install packages in pycharm.
In your pycharm, go to File>Settings>Project:[your-project-name]>Project Interpreter:
[image]

Click on the **+** sign:
and look for your package, in our condition ie. numpy. and click on install.

**viola problem solved**

Comment: i know this is an old question/answer.. but I'm missing how the issue of not getting C++ install recognized, turned into using the project settings to use as the installer. I can use terminal, or the project settings, both get the same error. FOr me, this popped up after upgrading from python 3.8 to 3.9 (and creating a new venv). This Levenshtein_search package is a sub package of dedup.  I can't get past the error (either via terminal or project settings)