# CMD is not installing my packages using pip

Tags: python, cmd, pip

Having errors on cmd as admin trying to install new modules even re-installed python to get newest version, and keeps failing!

Modules I have tried

```
pip install pyaudio
pip install smtplib
```

AND MANY Others

---

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\marcu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9lkkindd\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\marcu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9lkkindd\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dwdolxb5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9lkkindd\pyaudio\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\marcu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9lkkindd\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\marcu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9lkkindd\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dwdolxb5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Right there in the error message: `extension error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while installing lxml through pip: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949519/error-while-installing-lxml-through-pip-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: It might be a good idea to first read error messages, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you must download visual c++ 14 on microsoft website(optionnal) before! try after install
update your pip also!

try this link https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6776-visual-c-redistributable-package.html