# How to troubleshoot exit status 1 error in pip?

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

can someone help me please, I'm using python 3.8.2 and when I try to install several libraries by pip this error appears...

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\breno.fabio-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Breno.Fabio-PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5rl6ic8g\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Breno.Fabio-PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5rl6ic8g\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Breno.Fabio-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-c89rmvyo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Breno.Fabio-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5rl6ic8g\pyaudio\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\breno.fabio-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Breno.Fabio-PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5rl6ic8g\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Breno.Fabio-PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5rl6ic8g\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Breno.Fabio-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-c89rmvyo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile 
Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've tried to translate it on google translator and do what you ask...

Comment: But it says what the problem is, it expects and cannot find C++ compiler as apparently a package has some parts of it written in C++.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40886619/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671800/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while installing lxml through pip: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949519/error-while-installing-lxml-through-pip-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)