# How to resolve error while installing annoy using pip?

Tags: installation, pip, python-3.8, failed-installation, annoy

I have python 3.8 on my system.

I am trying to install Annoy using pip install annoy.

But I am getting the following error:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Faizan Hassan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_7d9h68q\\annoy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Faizan Hassan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_7d9h68q\\annoy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Faizan Hassan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-acbt5gft'
       cwd: C:\Users\Faizan Hassan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_7d9h68q\annoy\
  Complete output (10 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\annoy
  copying annoy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\annoy
  running build_ext
  building 'annoy.annoylib' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for annoy
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Faizan Hassan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_7d9h68q\\annoy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Faizan Hassan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_7d9h68q\\annoy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Faizan Hassan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0m5sse9_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\Include\annoy'
         cwd: C:\Users\Faizan Hassan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_7d9h68q\annoy\
    Complete output (10 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\annoy
    copying annoy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\annoy
    running build_ext
    building 'annoy.annoylib' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Faizan Hassan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_7d9h68q\\annoy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\`enter code here`Users\\Faizan Hassan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_7d9h68q\\annoy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Faizan Hassan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0m5sse9_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\Include\annoy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I get rid of this error? I have tried to look multiple related errors online but nothing seems to help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error even Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610212/pip-error-even-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-installed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949519/error-while-installing-lxml-through-pip-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the Microsoft Visual C++.
You can visit to this link. https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_BuildTools.exe and download all the required files.

Hope this will resolve your issue.
Thank you