# Unable to install neuralcoref : Coreference Resolution in spaCy with Neural Networks

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, pip, spacy, coreference-resolution

I am trying to install NeuralCoref using `pip install neuralcoref`. I already installed spaCy vesrion 3.0.6 and Visual Studio Build Tools version 16.9.5! However, I am still getting this error when running `pip install neuralcoref`:

```
 Complete output (25 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref
  copying neuralcoref\file_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref
  copying neuralcoref\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\tests
  copying neuralcoref\tests\test_neuralcoref.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\tests
  copying neuralcoref\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\tests
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\train
  copying neuralcoref\train\algorithm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\train
  copying neuralcoref\train\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\train
  copying neuralcoref\train\conllparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\train
  copying neuralcoref\train\dataset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\train
  copying neuralcoref\train\document.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\train
  copying neuralcoref\train\evaluator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\train
  copying neuralcoref\train\learn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\train
  copying neuralcoref\train\model.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\train
  copying neuralcoref\train\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\train
  copying neuralcoref\train\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\neuralcoref\train
  running build_ext
  building 'neuralcoref.neuralcoref' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for neuralcoref
```

I also tried reinstalling Visual Studio and restarting and it also didnt work. Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262038/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671800/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40886619/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Comment: I spent some time on it, and could only install it for the older Spacy version.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Spacy 2.1.0?

Comment: I can't remember, probably yes, as [stated in this Github issue](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref/issues/252).

Answer (score 1):

The neuralcoref package only supports spaCy 2, so you'll need to downgrade spaCy to use it. I would recommend using 2.3.5, the latest v2 release.

Answer (score 0):

For the accurate installation of neuralcoref : Coreference Resolution in spaCy with Neural Networks, below are the tested compatible versions in Ubuntu:

1. spacy==2.1.0
2. neuralcoref==4.0