# Pip can't install shap because of missing c++

Tags: python, c++, windows, pip

I'm trying to install the shap library using pip, on windows.

I get the error "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
"

I have tried installing it, selecting the c++ build tools, c++ redist and windows sdk (and many other libs that looked like they could work), but it still won't work.

I tried updating pip, setuptools and wheels, to no avail.

What else can I do ? Do I need to somehow tell pip where this is all installed ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do anything here help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40886619/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671800/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262038/7976758.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried adding various components but it still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the compiler shipped with visual studio (not visual studio code), it's the simplest workaround that i know of.

From the [python doc](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.0_standalone:_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_Build_Tools_2015_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.29):

Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 with Visual Studio 2015 (x86, x64, ARM)

Visual Studio 2015 contains Visual C++ 14.0 compiler. Distutils will automatically detect the compiler and use it.

So you need to:

1. install visual studio 2015 or latest
2. [install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=msvc-170) "Desktop development with C++" from the workloads
3. it's done

With the compiler is instaled this way there is no need to configure your pip or anything, all libs that need c++ compilation will be usable.

Answer (score 0):

Update: thank you for your answers.
I was eventually able to figure out a workaround: I installed shap through conda instead of pip, I believe conda uses a precompiled version.

It's a bit messy, but I only need shap for some experiments, so that'll do.