# Could not parse vswhere.exe output -- What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pip

I have tried to `pip install -r requirements_versions.txt` but I keep getting this error. I don't know much about python or programming to be honest, so excuse me if the answer is evident. Answers are much appreciated!

```
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvxifhen\scipy_ca2dfa1f687847469b8b0ab23841fd31 C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvxifhen\scipy_ca2dfa1f687847469b8b0ab23841fd31\.mesonpy-2yqzcl_i -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvxifhen\scipy_ca2dfa1f687847469b8b0ab23841fd31\.mesonpy-2yqzcl_i\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.3.0
      Source dir: C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvxifhen\scipy_ca2dfa1f687847469b8b0ab23841fd31
      Build dir: C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvxifhen\scipy_ca2dfa1f687847469b8b0ab23841fd31\.mesonpy-2yqzcl_i
      Build type: native build
      Project name: SciPy
      Project version: 1.9.3
      WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not parse vswhere.exe output

      ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvxifhen\scipy_ca2dfa1f687847469b8b0ab23841fd31\.mesonpy-2yqzcl_i\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

Comment: Some of the packages to install are written in C/C++ but don't provide precompiled wheels so you need a compiler. See these answers on how to install and configure VC++: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40888720/7976758 https://stackoverflow.com/a/40886619/7976758 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44953739/7976758 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671800/7976758 https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262038/7976758 Search through https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Comment: Or may be you can downgrade your Python to a version for which all precompiled wheels exist so you don't need to compile yourself. What is the problematic package?

Comment: I managed to install the required compilers. Thank you so much! I ran into the same problem with different compilers tho (Fortran), and even after trying to install them, I still get the same issue. I'll create a new question for that. Thank you again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

**You are most likely missing a C++ compiler**.

Installing Visual Studio with the C++ workload will fix this error.

See below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=msvc-170