# Pip install Scrappy - "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, pip

I am trying to install Scrappy. I have Python 3.6 installed and am on Windows.

I have tried this:

```
py -3.5-32 -m pip install Scrappy
```

However, got the following:

```
Collecting Scrappy
  Using cached Scrappy-0.3.0.alpha.4.tar.gz
Collecting guessit (from Scrappy)
  Using cached guessit-2.1.2.tar.gz
Collecting tvdb_api (from Scrappy)
  Using cached tvdb_api-1.10.tar.gz
Collecting hachoir-metadata (from Scrappy)
  Using cached hachoir-metadata-1.3.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\USER~1.NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1tu2hkos\hachoir-metadata\setup.py", line 65
        except OSError, err:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------   
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USER~1.NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1tu2hkos\hachoir-metadata\
```

Which is because of `setuptools`? So I upgraded it and then tried to install Scrappy but got the same error message.

Anybody know why this is happening?

Update, error when attempting to install Scrapy:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft
>   Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
>
> ```
>     ----------------------------------------
> Command "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe
> ```
>
> -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\USER~1.NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-j6ijek3o\Twisted\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\USER~1.NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-bmjl_u_2-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\USER~1.NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-j6ijek3o\Twisted\

Comment: Try using `pip3 --user`

Comment: I'm relatively new to Python and not heard of `pip3` is this what you mean? - `py -3.5-32 pip3 install Scrappy`?

Comment: From Scrapy [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows): Though it’s possible to install Scrapy on Windows using pip, we recommend you to install [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/).

Comment: [scrapy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Scrapy/1.3.3) or [scrappy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Scrappy/)? scrappy (with 2 p) does not look Python 3 compatible

Comment: Thanks @paultrmbrth I was trying to install Scrappy. Tried Scrapy, unfortunately no luck either!

Comment: Thanks @vold I think I will try that as nothing else seems to be working. Do you reckon it will install with conda?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking you are asking about the Scrapy framework. I can't tell you if Anaconda can help you with Scrappy. You should check their [package list](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs).

Comment: @Maverick, If you're trying to install [Scrappy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Scrappy), to _"rename video files based on information scraped from thetvdb.com"_, then I believe you need to use Python 2. Scrappy is not syntax-compatible with Python 3 ([nor does it seem maintained](https://github.com/louist87/Scrappy/commits/master)).

Comment: @vold I've installed it with conda, but can't seem to import it... Went back to conda to install it again `All requested packages already installed.` Tried it with pip out of curiosity and all requirements are installed. Restarted my machine, still can't import. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
pip install Scrapy
```

Scrapy, not scrappy

[Scrapy Installation Guide](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html)

Comment: I tried Scrapy and got, see update for error message.

Comment: @Maverick read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat