# ImportError: No module named pandas. Pandas installed pip

Tags: python, macos, pandas

I use the Mac terminal to check my package:

```sh
pip list
```

I can find all packages including [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29):

But when I

```py
import pandas
```

it told me:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

By the way, I have Python 2 and Python 3 on my Mac. They are not the same directory, and I suspect the Python interpreter didn't find the path of Pandas.

Comment: I suspect that you updated one python install, and you're running the other one...

Comment: If it's in "pip list" then it is installed but you're using the wrong Python version.

Comment: Which version of Python are you running when you're observing the ModuleNotFoundError?

Comment: i agree with you all,i use python3 when running programs while backage in one directory named python2.6, but i don't know how to change that

Comment: It may be helpful to begin using virtual environments. Alternatively, you could install Pandas for Python 3 using `pip3 install pandas`.

Comment: Try running `which python` to see which Python you are running

Comment: thank you all, i succeed with Nicholas  advice

Comment: Currently, four of the answers are not for Mac. Three of the answers are for Windows and one is for Ubuntu/Linux. One resolution could be to generalise the question and drop the Mac references.

Answer (score 22):

First of all, install `virtualenv` inside your project folder to secure your project directory to avoid conflict with your other packages.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

After installing this, run this command one by one inside your root project directory:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

Now *your* directory is secure and you can install your required packages inside.

```
pip install pandas
```

and others as you required.

Because you have installed `virtualenv` and running as secure, it will not conflict with other outside packages.

Use these all steps one by one.

Answer (score 19):

Try to install Pandas using [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29) and pip3:

```
pip install pandas

pip3 install pandas
```

A suggestion: Use pyenv and set a Python version for your local directory.

Comment: `pip3 install pandas` has worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If Python 2.7 is already installed, then to install [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) and [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) for v2.7, run the below commands:

For [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) / Linux -

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
```

If Python 3 is already installed, then to install NumPy and Pandas for v3, run the below commands:

For Ubuntu / Linux -

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

Comment: On ubuntu, "sudo apt-get install python3-pandas" worked. Why is that? This is so frustrating wasting so many hours trying to find stuff only on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

I had Python 2 and Python 3 installed in different directories, but I was facing this error, because when I was using the command `pip install pandas`, it was installing Pandas in Python 2 directories while I was using Python 3.

So I had two directories with `Python2 --> C:\Python27` and `Python365 --> C:\Python365`.

To resolve this error:

Run `pip install pandas` in `cmd`. If library Pandas is already installed, you'll see something like the following.

```
pip install pandas

Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (0.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.14.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2018.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.11.0)
```

From the output of above command you can see that `pandas` is installed in the `Python2` directory, i.e. `C:\python27\lib\site-packages` (0.23.4).

Run the `python` command in `cmd` to check which Python version are you running.

```
python

Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

You can see that I'm using `Python3` while Pandas is installed in the `Python2` directory.

To install Pandas and other libraries in `Python3` go to the scripts folder in `Python3 directory, i.e., C:\Python365\Scripts`.
Open a *Command window* and run `pip install pandas`.

Or you can use the *complete path of pip in the Python3 directory* in `cmd` to run the `install` command, i.e., `C:\Python365\Scripts\pip install pandas`

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably? The question says *"I have Python 2 and Python 3 on my Mac."*

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it might be due to an issue with [Microsoft Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B).

1. For that, first you need to install Microsoft Visual C++ using the instructions given in *[Error "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087)*
2. After successful installation, use `pip install pandas` to install Pandas
3. If `pip` is not installed, then download the Pandas source package with extension `tar.gz` and place it in directory wherever you want after extracting. Open `cmd.exe` and navigate to the path where the Pandas folder is extracted & placed using `cd C:/pandas`. Then install it using the `python setup.py install`

   Finally you should get the success message as

   > Finished processing dependencies for pandas==0.xx.0

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably? The question says *"I have Python 2 and Python 3 on my Mac."*

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost every suggestion under this question, but I still faced the issue and after a lot of struggle, I resolved this by the below steps.

> Run the command prompt as administrator and then enter the below.

```
pip install pandas
```

It helps you resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The error I saw was:

> File "c:\SIP\python\visualws\learn1\pandas_test.py", line 6, in
>
> import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I executed the below command in Windows using Python 3.9.5:

```
pip install pandas
```

#### Output

```
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.2.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (9.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 9.3 MB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting pytz>=2017.3
  Downloading pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 510 kB 6.8 MB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.16.5
  Downloading numpy-1.20.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (13.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 13.7 MB ...
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7.3
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 227 kB 6.4 MB/s
Collecting six>=1.5
  Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Installing collected packages: six, pytz, python-dateutil, numpy, pandas
Successfully installed numpy-1.20.3 pandas-1.2.4 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2021.1 six-1.16.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 21.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\deepy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

It solved the problem and I was able to execute the .py file with `import pandas`.

Comment: The question says *"I have Python 2 and Python 3 on my Mac."*