# Unable to run module

Tags: pandas

[image: Installation]

[image: import error]

After installing pandas, it still shows "No modules named pandas". What should I do?

Comment: what is output of `pip3 -V`?

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025899/importerror-no-module-named-pandas-pandas-installed-pip