# Pyto iOS does error when try to import Pandas

Tags: python, ios, pandas

Pyto on iOS has several packages included which is the reason I prefer it over Pythonista for iPad.

But although pandas is one of them I get an error when trying to import it:

import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I can use numpy, matplotlib etc without any issue.
Any idea why pandas is not working?

Thanks for any hint
Rolf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named pandas. Pandas installed pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025899/importerror-no-module-named-pandas-pandas-installed-pip)

Comment: Please note the question references Pyto on iOS specifically. @FluxedScript

Comment: @undoch
You are right. Unfortunately the answer from FluxedScript does not help. Thanks nevertheless!