# Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, msbuild, misaka

I have tried all methods mentioned on the internet but there is no use.
I am trying to install misaka by writing `pip install misaka` it keeps complaining by showing the same message. I have downloaded and installed MS build tool 2015 and 2017, Restarted my laptop. Whatever I did, couldn't figure out why it complains.
Python version 3.6.4
Windows 10

Comment: Not sure if MS build tool installs the VC redist runtime. VC 2017 is 14.0. Try getting the  redist files from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) and install them. Files are vc_redist.x86.exe and vc_redist.x64.exe.

Comment: @michael_heath I have installed even visual studio, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I finally got to solve this issue as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55575792/1612432

Answer (score 31):

To solve any of the following errors:

- "Failed building wheel for misaka"
- "Failed to build misaka"
- "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required"
- "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

The solution is:

1. Go to:  https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017
2. Select the free download under Visual Studio Community 2017

   - This will download the installer.
   - Run the installer
3. Now the most important step is to select what you need under the workload tab:

   - Under Windows there are 3 choices. ONLY check "Desktop development with C++"
   - Under Web & Cloud there are 7 choices. ONLY check Python development (I believe this is optional but I still did it).
4. Now go to your cmd and install the package:

   ```
   pip3 install misaka
   ```

[image: screenshoot of what you need to install]

Note that if you already installed Visual Studio then when you run the installer, you can modify it (click the modify button under Visual Studio Community 2017) and do steps 3 and 4.
[image]

Comment: I needed more. I run Visual Studio Installer -> Visual Studio Build Tools 2019. It preselected: C++ BUILD TOOLS C++ Build Tools core features C++ 2019 Redistributable Update C++ core desktop features OPTIONAL MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.28) Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0) C++ CMake tools for Windows Testing tools core features - Build Tools C++ AddressSanitizer (Experimental) MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00) INDIVIDUAL COMPONENTS Windows Universal CRT SDK MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)

Comment: How to do this via regular windows cmd?

Comment: - VS 2015 C++ build tools == VC 14.0; 
- VS 2017 C++ build tools == VC 14.1; 
- VS 2019 C++ build tools == VC 14.2;

Comment: Sharing an up to date link for the installer for the Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools : https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202017&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads

Answer (score 15):

Using the https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ installer only and selecting only four specific components helped solve the error.

[image: Build tools selection for spacy]

Comment: How to do this via regular windows cmd?

Answer (score 9):

I was getting the same error when trying to install biopython with Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

Installing just the Build Tools (instead of the full Community Edition as suggested in the other answer), with the options "C++/CLI support" and "VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop" checked in addition to the defaults, solved the problem.

Comment: How you did so?

Answer (score 6):

I did a variation of @Jason246 answer, to keep up with changes to the website.

I was having a problem with a `pip install spacy` that gave the same problem in the title.

This is running on a Windows 10 machine.

First, I went directly to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017 .

Then I clicked the Download button. The download was 71 Mb at the time. Then pressed the install button when the download ran. The install took a long time as it had to create a Windows restore point.

Then I started the installer and checked the following:

[image: Visual Studio components]

I selected

- Windows 10 SDK
- C++ CMake tools for Windows

(and the VS 2019 C++ came along for the ride).

I ran

`pip install spacy`

and am no longer getting the error for C++ 14.0.