# Installing MS C++ 14.0 for python without Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, msbuild

I am installing some python packages of an existed project and I am getting this error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft
Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I found a solution to that by installing it using one of the visual studio's products here [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541801/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-get-it-with-microsoft-visual-c-build-t), however, want to know if there is another way without needing to install more than 1.7 gb.
PS: I installed the standalone MSbuild tools and didn't work for me.

Comment: You might search for the package you want here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ 

download the package in a folder, open cmd or PS in the same folder and simply run `pip install name_of_package_downloaded` tab completion helps choosing file name

Comment: "I installed the standalone MSbuild tools and didn't work for me" --> Which installer did you use?

Comment: "didn't work for me" --> do you have the most current version of `setuptools` installed?

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes I did upgraded the setuptools

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Installing MS C++ 14.0 for python without Visual Studio

To install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, you can download the Microsoft [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15), install and open it, select: **Workloads** → **Visual C++ build tools**(Even you can only select only the "Windows 10 SDK"):

[image]

If above still not resolve your issue, you can try to switch to **Individual components**, scrolling down the list of **Individual** components, there was a section titled Compilers, build tools, and runtimes. Under that section there was a **VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset for desktop (x86,x64)** option and select it:

[image]

I have installed both of them, so I can not make sure which one is installed to solve this issue.

Besides, someone give a another workaround to resolve this issue, you can check if it works for you:

> One way around is to install precompiled binaries. The webpage
>   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs (mirror) contains
>   precompiled binaries for many Python packages. After downloading the
>   package of interest to you, you can install it using pip install, e.g.
>   `pip install mysqlclient‑1.3.10‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl`.

You can check [this document](https://www.scivision.co/python-windows-visual-c++-14-required/) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

**You can avoid large downloads with another setup file.**

To install MS C++ 14.0 only:

1. download [visualcppbuildtools_full.exe](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe.) file and execute.
2. unselect all the checkboxes (to avoid large download).
3. install button will be shown, click it.

restart pc and you are up to it.

Answer (score 2):

Following the installation link specified by [@Leo Liu-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52397318/5912896), I selected below two options only and the issue get resolved without restarting my machine.
[image]