# PIP Install Python module with C++ build || fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winpty.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, pip

When I try the following prompt in a Windows cmd:

```
python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

Or with this prompt:

```
pip install pyroomacoustics
```

I get the following error in response to both:

```
winpty/cywinpty.c(629): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winpty.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Most of these modules above have C++ programming associated with it especially pyroomacoustics. Is there a way to get this winpty.h file within the directory in question or another work around to solve this issue?

I've already installed the visual C++ build tools based on another answer from a previous issue I had with this pip install:
[Installing MS C++ 14.0 for python without Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383577/installing-ms-c-14-0-for-python-without-visual-studio)