# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: (Command Prompt)

Tags: python, pip

I get an error with my command prompt. I tried `pip install notebook` from Jupyter, but some errors came. I appreciate anyone who views or answers, thanks for your time!

[image]

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\ali\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ali\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1eke7zh0\\pywinpty_541aba1e831148ec8ed9409eefc720d1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ali\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1eke7zh0\\pywinpty_541aba1e831148ec8ed9409eefc720d1\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-brdl12uh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\ali\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pywinpty'
         cwd: C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1eke7zh0\pywinpty_541aba1e831148ec8ed9409eefc720d1\
    Complete output (19 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\winpty
    copying winpty\ptyprocess.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\winpty
    copying winpty\winpty_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\winpty
    copying winpty\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\winpty
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\winpty\tests
    copying winpty\tests\test_cywinpty.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\winpty\tests
    copying winpty\tests\test_ptyprocess.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\winpty\tests
    copying winpty\tests\test_winpty_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\winpty\tests
    copying winpty\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\winpty\tests
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\winpty\_winpty
    copying winpty\_winpty\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\winpty\_winpty
    running build_ext
    building 'winpty.cywinpty' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\ali\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ali\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1eke7zh0\\pywinpty_541aba1e831148ec8ed9409eefc720d1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ali\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1eke7zh0\\pywinpty_541aba1e831148ec8ed9409eefc720d1\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-brdl12uh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\ali\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pywinpty' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's not clear about the error message "*error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/*"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing MS C++ 14.0 for python without Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383577/installing-ms-c-14-0-for-python-without-visual-studio)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error message includes: 
`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

So go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ and install `Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools`.