# How do I install wordcloud

Tags: python, dataframe, pip, visualization, word-cloud

I used `pip install wordcloud` on the command prompt but I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried installing `Microsoft C++ Build Tools` from : https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ but I still get the same error. I have also upgraded my `pip` version from `21.3` to `21.3.1`

Any help would be appretiated thanks in advance.

Comment: When you installed the build tools, what did you actually select in the installer? You'd have to select "Desktop development with C++" in order to have the Visual C++ redistributables installed; did you do that?

Comment: Hi Random Davis , I don't think I did that let me try installing again. I will revert to you with an answer shortly.

Comment: So the "Desktop development with C++" gives me some other sub-options to install. which ones do I choose?

Comment: Just install all the options it automatically selects, I've never actually used it before but it should just by default install what you need. I recommend looking at RustyPython's answer though, that should be a way simpler solution.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of error messages, copy past the error into your question instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Answer (score 1):

Pip is trying to install from setup.py file, which requires compiling some C extensions, that's why it's asking for the build tools.
The error message says that it's using setup.py because it can't find the `wheel` package.

Install the `wheel` package first, then try again.
`pip install wheel`

Comment: I just installed the wheel package then tried to install wordcloud again but I still get an error. But I think I did check "Desktop development with C++" when installing the Built tools so I'm trying that now.

Comment: Ah, just had a look at the worldcloud package on pypi and realised my answer won't work. From your error message I can see that you are on windows and are running CPython 3.9. Worldcloud does not have a .whl for python 3.9 on windows, only Linux so it has to use the source tar.gz which will require the C++ build tools. Your options are to find the right options for C++ build tool install or if you have Python 3.8 installed, there is a .whl available so you wouldn't need the build tools.

Comment: This stack overflow should help with build tools options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383577/installing-ms-c-14-0-for-python-without-visual-studio