# Can't figure out how to install this python module on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-module

I've been trying to install a module called [BioPython](https://biopython.org/wiki/Download) on Windows 7, but everytime I try to do a pip install I get this back:

```
Command "c:\users\mqian\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u
-c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\mqian\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
\\pip-install-e0z5nqc6\\biopython\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(_
_file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file
__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\mqian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fsxh
7if9\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed wi
th error code 1 in C:\Users\mqian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e0z5nqc6\biopyt
hon\
```

Some googling and StackOverflowing hasn't resulted in anything helpful. I've looked at some SO posts on error code 1 to no avail. Any one have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try installing the Anaconda Environment and then doing `conda install -c anaconda biopython`

Answer (score 1):

So I took a look at my stack trace and it seems I missed an important line in all the jumble of output it gave me.

These two links were somewhat helpful.

[Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualst udio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541801/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-get-it-with-microsoft-visual-c-build-t)

Essentially I was missing this tool (of which I'm not entirely sure of its use yet). According to the second link if any of the following appear: `Failed building wheel for [your module]` or `Failed to build [your module]` or `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required` or `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`, then you probably need to install visual c++.

Either way, installing it solved my problem. Cheers.