# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools"

Tags: python-3.x, windows, visual-studio, powershell

This is the error it gives when I tried installing some Python (3.8) packages, so i installed it from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ , but it still gives me the same error. 
By the way, pip is at the latest version; and i installed visual studio without any workloads, since the error message didn't ask for any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualst udio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541801/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-get-it-with-microsoft-visual-c-build-t)

Comment: @Mutantoe Yes it does, thanks!