# cx_Oracle Module not found

Tags: python, cmd, cx-oracle

Whenever I try to import cx_Oracle in pyCharm or Visual Studio it gives an error saying "cx_Oracle module not found". And if I try to install cx_Oracel using the command prompt, it again gives an error saying "Command errored out with exit status 1"[This is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjfG8.png).
So please help me with installing cx_Oracle successfully.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541801/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-get-it-with-microsoft-visual-c-build-t)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is highly recommended to add text information like code, errors and logs as a text not images. As for the error it is quite self-explanatory: you need "Build Tools for Visual Studio".

Comment: Yeah that solved the problem @SergeyShubin, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Prebuilt binaries for Python 3.9 are not available yet. You can choose Python 3.6
through Python 3.8 instead, or you can get the necessary build tools for Windows. The simplest solution is to simply use Python 3.8 for now.