# Trying to install pandas with pip throws 2000+ lines and an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, pip

Hello I'm not much of a programmer so bear with me. I am working on a computer with both python 2.7 and python 3.10. Both are the 32 bit versions. I'm working on updating some things to python 3 and I need the pandas package.

When I run `pip3 install pandas`

It has consistently given me this error:

```
  Using cached pandas-1.4.3.tar.gz (4.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in c:\users\dg5dvd3\appdata\local\programs\python\python310-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\dg5dvd3\appdata\local\programs\python\python310-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\dg5dvd3\appdata\local\programs\python\python310-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\dg5dvd3\appdata\local\programs\python\python310-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2038 lines of output]
      C:\Users\DG5DVD3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hl0hes1o\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:463: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas
      copying pandas\conftest.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas
      copying pandas\testing.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas
      copying pandas\_typing.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas
      copying pandas\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas
      copying pandas\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\api
      copying pandas\api\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\api
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\arrays
      copying pandas\arrays\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\arrays
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\compat
      copying pandas\compat\chainmap.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\compat
      copying pandas\compat\pickle_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\compat
      copying pandas\compat\pyarrow.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\compat
      copying pandas\compat\_optional.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\compat
      copying pandas\compat\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\compat
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\accessor.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\algorithms.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\api.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\apply.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\arraylike.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\base.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\common.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\config_init.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\construction.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\describe.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\flags.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\frame.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\generic.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\index.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\indexing.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\missing.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\nanops.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\resample.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\roperator.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\sample.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\series.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\shared_docs.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\sorting.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      copying pandas\core\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\errors
      copying pandas\errors\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\errors
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\api.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\clipboards.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\common.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\date_converters.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\feather_format.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\gbq.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\html.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\orc.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\parquet.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\pickle.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\pytables.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\spss.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\sql.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\stata.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\xml.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      copying pandas\io\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\io
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\plotting
      copying pandas\plotting\_core.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\plotting
      copying pandas\plotting\_misc.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\plotting
      copying pandas\plotting\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\plotting
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_aggregation.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_algos.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_common.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_downstream.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_errors.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_expressions.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_flags.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_multilevel.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_nanops.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_optional_dependency.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_register_accessor.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_sorting.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\test_take.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      copying pandas\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tests
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tseries
      copying pandas\tseries\api.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tseries
      copying pandas\tseries\frequencies.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tseries
      copying pandas\tseries\holiday.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tseries
      copying pandas\tseries\offsets.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tseries
      copying pandas\tseries\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\tseries
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\util
      copying pandas\util\testing.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\util
      copying pandas\util\_decorators.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\util
      copying pandas\util\_doctools.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\util
      copying pandas\util\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\util
      copying pandas\util\_print_versions.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\util
      copying pandas\util\_tester.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\util
      copying pandas\util\_test_decorators.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\util
      copying pandas\util\_validators.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\util
      copying pandas\util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\util
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_config
      copying pandas\_config\config.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_config
      copying pandas\_config\dates.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_config
      copying pandas\_config\display.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_config
      copying pandas\_config\localization.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_config
      copying pandas\_config\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_config
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_libs
      copying pandas\_libs\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_libs
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_testing
      copying pandas\_testing\asserters.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_testing
      copying pandas\_testing\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_testing
      copying pandas\_testing\contexts.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_testing
      copying pandas\_testing\_hypothesis.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_testing
      copying pandas\_testing\_io.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_testing
      copying pandas\_testing\_random.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_testing
      copying pandas\_testing\_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_testing
      copying pandas\_testing\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_testing
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\api\extensions
      copying pandas\api\extensions\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\api\extensions
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\api\indexers
      copying pandas\api\indexers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\api\indexers
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\api\types
      copying pandas\api\types\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\api\types
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\compat\numpy
      copying pandas\compat\numpy\function.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\compat\numpy
      copying pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\compat\numpy
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\base.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\boolean.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\floating.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\integer.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\interval.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\masked.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\numeric.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\numpy_.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\period.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\string_.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\string_arrow.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\timedeltas.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\_arrow_utils.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\_mixins.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\_ranges.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      copying pandas\core\arrays\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\arrays
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\array_algos
      copying pandas\core\array_algos\masked_reductions.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\array_algos
      copying pandas\core\array_algos\putmask.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\array_algos
      copying pandas\core\array_algos\quantile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\array_algos
      copying pandas\core\array_algos\replace.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\array_algos
      copying pandas\core\array_algos\take.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\array_algos
      copying pandas\core\array_algos\transforms.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\array_algos
      copying pandas\core\array_algos\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\array_algos
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\align.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\api.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\check.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\common.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\engines.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\eval.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\expr.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\expressions.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\ops.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\parsing.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\pytables.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\scope.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      copying pandas\core\computation\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\computation
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\dtypes
      copying pandas\core\dtypes\api.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\dtypes
      copying pandas\core\dtypes\base.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\dtypes
      copying pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\dtypes
      copying pandas\core\dtypes\common.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\dtypes
      copying pandas\core\dtypes\concat.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\dtypes
      copying pandas\core\dtypes\dtypes.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\dtypes
      copying pandas\core\dtypes\generic.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\dtypes
      copying pandas\core\dtypes\inference.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\dtypes
      copying pandas\core\dtypes\missing.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\dtypes
      copying pandas\core\dtypes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\dtypes
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\groupby
      copying pandas\core\groupby\base.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\groupby
      copying pandas\core\groupby\categorical.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\groupby
      copying pandas\core\groupby\generic.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\groupby
      copying pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\groupby
      copying pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\groupby
      copying pandas\core\groupby\indexing.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\groupby
      copying pandas\core\groupby\numba_.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\groupby
      copying pandas\core\groupby\ops.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\groupby
      copying pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\groupby
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\indexers
      copying pandas\core\indexers\objects.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\indexers
      copying pandas\core\indexers\utils.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\indexers
      copying pandas\core\indexers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\indexers
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\indexes
      copying pandas\core\indexes\accessors.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\indexes
      copying pandas\core\indexes\api.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\indexes
      copying pandas\core\indexes\base.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\indexes
      copying pandas\core\indexes\category.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\indexes
      copying pandas\core\indexes\datetimelike.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\indexes
      copying pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\indexes
      copying pandas\core\indexes\extension.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\core\indexes
      


      *1000+ more lines of this stuff*^



      running egg_info
      writing pandas.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pandas.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing entry points to pandas.egg-info\entry_points.txt
      writing requirements to pandas.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to pandas.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'pandas.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bz2' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.csv' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dta' found anywhere in distribution



      *A bunch more of these*^

       

      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'pandas.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      C:\Users\DG5DVD3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hl0hes1o\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:153: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning:     Installing 'pandas._libs.src' as data is deprecated, please list it in `packages`.
          !!


          ############################
          # Package would be ignored #
          ############################
          Python recognizes 'pandas._libs.src' as an importable package,
          but it is not listed in the `packages` configuration of setuptools.

          'pandas._libs.src' has been automatically added to the distribution only
          because it may contain data files, but this behavior is likely to change
          in future versions of setuptools (and therefore is considered deprecated).

          Please make sure that 'pandas._libs.src' is included as a package by using
          the `packages` configuration field or the proper discovery methods
          (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
          instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

          You can read more about "package discovery" and "data files" on setuptools
          documentation page.


          *A lot more of these "package would be ignored" messages*^





        check.warn(importable)
      copying pandas\_libs\algos.pxd -> build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas\_libs



      *And more of these once again*^




      UPDATING build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas/_version.py
      set build\lib.win32-cpython-310\pandas/_version.py to '1.4.3'
      running build_ext
      building 'pandas._libs.algos' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based project
```

Apologies for not being able to paste the whole message it was about 2000+ lines

Things I've tried:

- Downgrading pip
- updating Microsoft Visual C++
- uninstalling pandas for python 2 with `pip uninstall pandas` and the trying to install it again  with `pip3 install pandas`
- checking my Path in environment variables. which is set to AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32 for python 3 and C:\Python27 for 2. Python two's path is above it on the list.

I also installed panda on python 3.10 with pip on a seperate computer with no python 2 and there was 0 issue. The only difference was that this python was 64 bit.

I assume this has something to do with having two versions of python on this computer. I need have both versions for reference reasons.

If anyone can help me with this, you would be my savior. I've been struggling with what to do now for a while.

Answer (score 0):

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

My bet is on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541801/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-get-it-with-microsoft-visual-c-build-t), but use the build tools link from your message, that thread is 4 years old.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it! Honestly I tried this earlier and it didn't seem to do anything. Thanks so much for the reply.