# ERROR: Could not build wheels for frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to install discord.py , but I get this error out. pip updated immediately I say.

[image]

I reinstalled python, pip and so on, I installed in pycharm both from PythonInterpreter and through the terminal.

```
× Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [98 lines of output]
      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      **********************
      * Accelerated build *
      **********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running egg_info
      writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      running build_ext
      building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 249, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 412, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 397, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 484, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 86, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 84, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 346, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 466, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 492, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 246, in build_extension
          _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 547, in build_extension
          objects = self.compiler.compile(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 344, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
          vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 214, in msvc14_get_vc_env
          return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0gyts2a3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 168, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
          raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
      setuptools._distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build frozenlist multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? "*setuptools._distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/*"

Comment: Yes, I read the error, but I don't understand anything since I'm just learning. no one helped me on the Internet, I had to write a question

Comment: I gave you the relevant line in italics in my previous comment. You need Microsoft's C/C++ compiler (also known as MSVC) command-line tools in order to build the C/C++ extensions in those modules. C and C++ are compiled languages, you can't just run the source code like you can with Python. Go to the link I gave, click on Download Build Tools, run the downloaded file `vs_BuildTools.exe` as an administrator, and go from there.

Comment: thank you very much, to be honest, I most likely did not see the correctly posed question in the terminal and did not understand what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Installation on Windows 11 of pandasAI under Python 3.12.0 went bad. Error message told me that VS C++ Build Tools were missing, but installing this did not solve the error.
Searching github [revealed](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/3483) that the true error is that aiohttp doesn't work on Python 3.12.
Therefore I installed python 3.11.6 also and created a 3.11-based virtual environment using

- py -3.11 -m venv \pandasai3.11

After activating it installation of pandasAI went very well. In a command-box:

- \pandasai3.11\scripts\activate
- cd \pandasai3.11
- pip install pandasai

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to investigate the error message in your log:
`Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools"`

Here is related question: [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48541801/1455694)

---

Also the following may be helpful. I had the exact description of the error as in title of this question but for `aiohttp`, `yarl` and `frozenlist` modules. Just in case will leave here the description of encountered error and the solution.

The error below I got while executing `pip install -r requirements.txt` for installation I made:

```
socket.c -o build/temp.linux-armv8l-cpython-311/aiohttp/_websocket.o
aiohttp/_websocket.c:198:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
#include "longintrepr.h"                                   
          ^~~~~~~                        1 error generated.
error: command '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang' 
failed with exit code 1
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install
pyproject.toml-based projects
```

This error is specific to Python `3.11` version. On Python with `3.10.6` version installation went fine.

To solve it I needed to update `requirements.txt`.

Not working versions of modules with Python `3.11`:

```
aiohttp==3.8.1
yarl==1.4.2
frozenlist==1.3.0
```

Working versions:

```
aiohttp==3.8.2
yarl==1.8.1
frozenlist==1.3.1
```

Links to the corresponding issues with fixes:

- https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/6600
- https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/issues/706
- https://github.com/aio-libs/frozenlist/issues/305

Answer (score 1):

Just install Python 3.10.8 version

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).