# Getting this ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python

I am trying to install discord.py for a bot I am building but getting the following error.

```
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build aiohttp frozenlist multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
PS C:\Users\User>
```

I  have tried this solution but I am still having the same error.

[ERROR: Could not build wheels for frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255709/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-frozenlist-multidict-yarl-which-is-required)

Comment: The actual error message is the part above `[end of output]`. Can you show us that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue: fixed by re-installing VSCode with all added packages. Then re-installing wheel.