# Fail to install batman package (package for modeling a light curve of exoplanet)

Tags: python, distutils, anaconda3

I tried to install the package using this command on anaconda prompt

```
pip install batman-package
```

As the tutorial on this website https://github.com/lkreidberg/batman/issues/26 said, but it didn't work. Here is the error:

[error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NkwL.png)

I have installed Microsoft Visual Code and the version is 16.0++, which I think should fix it based on what the error text said. I also try to follow a step to modify the distutils.cfg file as the tutorila on the website above, but I don't find any file named 'ditutils.cfg' so I made one, but still got the same error. does anyone know to fix this?

Comment: Please embed the error into your question instead of providing a link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541801/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-get-it-with-microsoft-visual-c-build-t)