# cannot install scikit-bio in my window 7 with anaconda 3.x (64-bit)

Tags: python, skbio

I used the following code to install scikit-bio from Spyder 3, but it showed error. Therefore, could anyone please help? many thanks

Code:
    import pip 
    pip.main (['install', 'scikit-bio'])

Error:
Command "C:\Users\vanna\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pythonw.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\vanna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_nvm7kff\scikit-bio\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\vanna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-cpfgc63d-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\vanna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_nvm7kff\scikit-bio\

Comment: I still cannot fix this problem until now, but I would recommend to those who wish to use similar tools in Scikit-bio to another package so-called ecopy since it has similar functions or tools (e.g. PCA, CCA...).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message during pip installation on CPython (Win 10 x64). 
Upgrading setuptools

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

and installing build tools for most recent Visual Studio resolved the issue.
Just like here.
[Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)