# Mysqlclient installation Error

Tags: python, django

Python 3.4 and Django installed successfully, but when I want to install MySql Client using this command:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

it shows

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required.

But I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 10 and 14 and Visual Studio Community too.

Can anybody help me to get out of this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score -1):

Try using

`pip -V`

To check the version of pip you are using, I suspect it may be using Python version 2 to install when you want it in your Python 3 version.

If this is the case, try:

`pip3.4 install mysqlclient`

If this doesn't work I'd suggest using a different version of Python, perhaps a later version.

If that doesn't work try uninstalling then reinstalling all instances of visual studio and microsoft visual C++.