# distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Tags: pandas

I would like to install `Pandas` on my machine but the following message occurs:

> Error:distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "**Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools**": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

I installed **Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools** but my machine(pycharm) did't still adjust it.

In this problem, what should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/55575792#55575792