# how to use 'import scrapy' in .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

when I am writing ' import scrapy ' to import this library in my python file, on running it is giving error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'" and i have also installed scrapy using

```
pip install scrapy


#enter code here
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import scrapy


i = input('enter the item to be searched :')
i = i.replace(" ","")
sauce1 = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss? 
url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords='+i).read()
soup1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce1,'lxml')

s_url = []

ul_parent = soup1.find('div', class_='a-row s-result-list-parent-container')    

for url in ul_parent.find_all('a'):
    if "javascript" not in str(url.get('href')):
        s_url.append(str(url.get('href')))
print(s_url)
```

what should I do to import scrapy as I want to extract items from Amazon website using "response.xpath". Please help
Thank You

Comment: Have you installed scrapy?

Comment: install it, import it, done?

Answer (score 0):

you would have not installed Scrapy.

Please check in the installed list of libraries to verify the same by 
`pip list`

for installation details you can refer: [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html)

Comment: I have tried this... I have installed scrapy . it is working in its project that is created by "create scrapyproject name"

Comment: Did you run pip list and confirm scrapy is installed?Are you creating scrapy project in virtual env?

Answer (score 0):

1.Install Scrapy for your python version

```
    pip install scrapy
```

2. And then import it into your python file

```
    import scrapy
```

Comment: I have tried this... I have installed scrapy . it is working in its project that is created by "create scrapyproject name"

Comment: navigate to your Python/Scripts path and run pip freeze or pip list and check whether your scarpy is installed or not.@Ishan Verma

Comment: it is not showing scrapy in pip list. buti hv installed it. now what should i do to place it on that list
Now i tried to install scrapy in my Python/Scripts folder by setting path in cmd
and i am getting error
"error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools" - @Meghana Goud

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) try to upgrade your setup tools and check  whether Python/Scripts is added to your system path (environmental variables)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install scrapy using `pip install scrapy` and try to import scrapy.

Comment: I have tried this... I have installed scrapy . it is working in its project that is created by "create scrapyproject name"