# Installing pyodbc for Python 3.7 on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am a newbie to python and I need to connect to SQL Server.  I run the following command in my DB_Connect.py file.  I run python DB_Connect.py from CMD line and it gives error on `import pyodbc`.

[Pic of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Aun.png)

I then I ran command `pip install pyodbc` but it give an error saying, "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required".  I installed "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable" to accommodate this because I would need to get a license for a full version.  My understanding is that this will work.  I still get this error:

[Pic of pip install pyodbc err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1casP.png)

Do I need to install a full version of Visual C++ or is there a free option?  Why doesnt this CMD work with the Redistributable version?  How do I get past this step?

PC: windows 7 pro - 64
Python Version: 3.7.0

Comment: Why downwoting this. I'm a long time pyodbc user and this is an important issue. Creating the wheels should be a nightly build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2018-08-15**

pyodbc 4.0.24, released today, now includes Python 3.7 wheels for installing on Windows and Mac via `pip`.

---

*(original answer)*

pyodbc wheel files for Python 3.7 are not yet available on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/). They have been requested via the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/417).

You could always revert to Python 3.6 for the time being. Or, if you *really need* Python 3.7 *right now* then you'll have to install the required Visual Studio components so `pip` can build pyodbc from source. Details [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Building-pyodbc-from-source#windows).

> I then I ran command pip install pyodbc but it give an error saying, "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required". I installed "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable" to accommodate this

That didn't work because you installed the runtime support for Visual C++. You need the build tools for Visual C++, described [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers).

Comment: I just got back into town and thanks for the suggestion, everything worked out as expected.

Comment: @jujulalu: if it helped you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
pip install --only-binary :all: pyodbc
```

More about above:
[Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/51087608#51087608)