# Trying to pip install mysqlclient but getting error

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am trying to set up the environment to build a picture sharing app. The setup was going well until I had to install mysqlclient which is one of the requirements according to the tutorial I was using.

The error I get in the windows Powershell is this:

```
--compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

I already have Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 installed in my machine
I even tried upgrading setup tools like suggested in another post but with no luck
I have python 3.7 installed

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient﻿
```

Hope it helped.