# Python - Error when trying to pip cx_Freeze==5.0.2

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am trying to install `cx_Freeze==5.0.2` on Windows 8.1 / Python 3.7 but I am getting this Error:

[image]

I do not know what exactly cx_Freeze is for or why i need this version - it is from a requirements text file that threw and error, and this module is the only one that i could not install manually.

It says something about Visual C++ above, but I do have it installed, so I dont know why its saying that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: I do have Visual C++ 14 though, do i just have to add the install path to PATH?

Answer (score 0):

cx_Feeze needs compiling to run (this is usually done for you on Windows but it has not been done for 3.7 yet (see the [releases on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/cx_Freeze/#files)) so you have two options:

- Wait until it is (shouldn't be more than a few days/weeks, it wasn't last time python updated in any case)
- Compile it yourself

In the case of compiling, if you have VS installed then you probably have not set the correct environment variables

```
SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
SET MSSdk=1
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/28617830#28617830).

I would recomend [the answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/28617830) over the duplicate suggested above.