# python module installation error . asking for visual c++ 14.0

Tags: python

I am trying to install jupyter notebook using command line.
command used:

```
c:pip install jupyter
```

error messages display on cmd interface.

```
raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ANILKU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2gl7dpxn\pywinpty\
```

I am stuck here , I have alreday installed visual c++ redistribution 14.0. How to resolve it. Kindly answer if anybody knows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Just a recommendation, try to install every new package in a virtual environment first. If you directly install it on your system, you might commit some mistake and would not be able to undo it (or able to find the right file which was edited). Faulty installations can mess up your systems real bad.

Comment: how to do that? please explain.