# "pip install mysqlclient" requires microsoft visual c++ error

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

I do installed **Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0**, But while running **pip install mysqlclient**. Please, can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hKLF.png)

Comment: try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: No need to download the vs. Look at this answer for more details [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59878647/4000266)

Answer (score 3):

pip install mysqlclient:

1. In this web download the package
   [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-client](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-client) download 32
   or 64 version python version based your python version.
2. Put it to the directory (virtual folder).
3. In command prompt run `pip install mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` (based on your python version).

Another way: use this command

```
pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
```

Comment: I have tried pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient, it does not work, it errors out with 'no matching dist found for mysqlclient'

Comment: Put the  mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl in your python's virtual folder.