# Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.

Tags: scrapy

when i install scrapy package,The following error occurred:

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

but the website is not found,so how to solve the problem?

Comment: I finally got to solve this issue as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55575792/1612432

Answer (score 3):

The package is asking for the VS2015 build tools, [which are now available as part of the VS2017 build tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/11/02/visual-studio-build-tools-now-include-the-vs2017-and-vs2015-msvc-toolsets/). Download them [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017), or more specifically, [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15).

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the latest version of the Visual Studio. By version 14.0, only Visual Studio 2015 is required, but to provide support for further releases and some other programs and libraries that you might use, it is recommended to install the latest (Visual Studio 2017) which also comes with the 2015.

That link does not work, but you can find the new here: [Visual Studio Build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

Make sure to **tick** "Languages->C++". It should be automatic, but just to make sure.

Also, you probably would want to upgrade your setup tools for Python, **setuptools**.
You can do this with:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

The reason you would want to do that is, based on experience, because that error can continue to persist with Python even after you install the Visual Studio and the setup tools are not up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into issues getting this to work on Python 2 and 3 even after re-downloading Microsoft Visual tools, upgrading setuptools, and trying to install scrapy again.

Workaround solution that worked for me:
I already had an installation of Anaconda and was able to install Scrapy using Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

1. Visit https://pypi.org/project/Scrapy/#files
2. Download the latest 'Wheel' file-type
3. pip install "downloaded.whl" (i.e., pip install Scrapy-1.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl)