# How to fix "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using *path*/scrapy.exe" in anaconda?

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda, virtualenv

I am trying to install scrapy on Windows 10, 
By following these tutorials: 
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html
https://www.accordbox.com/blog/scrapy-tutorial-4-how-install-scrapy-windows/

After installing with anaconda using `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`, 
I write "scrapy" in anaconda prompt
and [get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdClh.png):

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\bld\scrapy_1564100571450\_h_env\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Rodzice.Mateusz-PC\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy.exe" '
```

also `scrapy -h` yields almost the same information, with -h on the end

typing `scrapy startproject x` in cmd gives

```
'scrapy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My [environmental](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIU3R.png) variables do not have any spaces.

Also I have tried creating virtualenv and installing scrapy inside of it. 
The error i [got](https://pastebin.com/5ahFxrqU)

I have got newest Microsoft Visual C++

Comment: I am using anaconda on window and was facing same issue. **python -m scrapy startproject scrapy_poc** cmd work for me. Might help other.

Comment: @Nitendra this works like a charm! tried many other steps but couldnt solve it

Comment: If you did a conda based scrapy installation, first uninstall scrapy : conda uninstall scrapy. And then do : pip install scrapy . Worked like a charm for python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

run anaconda prompt as administrator and install Scrapy

1. pip install scrapy

check the version as scrapy install correctly

2. scrapy -v

now run anaconda prompt without administrator

3. scrapy startproject example

Answer (score 0):

For installing scrapy you don't need to install Anaconda.

```
1. Make sure that you have python in your system.
2. Create a virtualenv (pip install virtualenv)
3. Install scrapy (pip install scrapy)
```

Comment: I also did it. I created virtualenv, and inside of it i tried use pip install scrapy. This is log I was given in cmd :https://pastebin.com/5ahFxrqU

Comment: you need to install some of the visual studio tools to support scrapy in windows. check the links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927014/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541801/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-get-it-with-microsoft-visual-c-build-t

Comment: if you use windows, you have to use anaconda, it is in the scrapy documentation