# PIP INSTALL CROSSBAR gives error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":

Tags: python, c++, django, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have been trying to `pip install crossbar` on my virtual environment in Windows 10 but I keep getting:

**error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools**

**I am using Python3.7 and Django2.1**

I have installed the requirement and have restarted my system severally but still getting the same error. `Pip` has been upgraded too.

Here is the list of programs install from my Control Panel:

[image: Control Panel]

And here is the Command Prompt error (again)[image: Command Prompt]

I have equally installed **Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable**, both (x86) and (x64) but still did not work.

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit version of Python 2.7.x as stated in the [documentation](https://crossbar.io/docs/Installation-on-Windows/#installing-the-dependencies)?

Comment: No. I am using Python3.7 and Django 2.1

Comment: @VTT that has been installed too. It is the first in the picture of Control Panel programs attached in the question.

Comment: Are they actually available when you run this script? Maybe you need to launch it in properly set up console? Try running this script inside of Visual Studio x86 native tools command prompt. You can type `cl.exe /?` to verify that compiler is available.

Comment: @VTT that gives error `'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`.

Comment: Then try running this from x86 native tools command prompt

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: install the Build tools not the redist files: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: @Yax Read the documentation again, crossbar.io is only compatible with Python 2.7 32-bit.

Comment: @magicandre1981 if you look at the first image, you can see it is the first in the programs installed.

Answer (score 0):

The redistributable files are used to **run** software which someone else **built**. You need the build tools themselves. Either get them as part of Visual Studio (which is free for personal use) or as part of the **Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools**.

The current toolset is [14.0/14.1](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) corresponding to VS2015/2017.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading setuptools

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40888720/8518309)