# Python - PyAudio installation error "failed with exit status 2"

Tags: python, pyaudio

I was trying to install PyAudio on Python 3.7.

First of all i got an error message "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required" which was resolved by installing Visual Studio 2017.

But now I'm getting a new error :

> c1: fatal error C1048: unknown option 'L' in '-ZILP448'    error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
>   failed with exit status 2

I am running Windows 10 64bit.

Also, I followed this post to find the first [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) :

Comment: Please provide [all the means to reproduce the problem, including your configuration, exact command and full output](/help/mcve).

Comment: For starters, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017` means you have VS2017 rather that 2015 as you claim.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the configuration is available for only x86 compilers. Try to turn off this option in the:

> Project Property Pages | Common Properties | C/C++ | Advanced | Enable
>   Code Analysis for C/C++ entry

[Reference](https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/509643-x64-c1xxast-fatal-error-c1048-unknown-option-l-zilp448)