# Errors in downloading the python modules using pip

Tags: pip, python-module, python-3.7

often I face the same error during downloading the python modules using pip. Could you guys help me sort this out? FYI I am using python 3.7v.

```
C:\>pip install PyAudio
Collecting PyAudio
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyAudio ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\avinash.tripathy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AVINAS~1.TRI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_qfc03y7\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\AVINAS~1.TRI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-fjb2zkz4 --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for PyAudio
  Running setup.py clean for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\avinash.tripathy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AVINAS~1.TRI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_qfc03y7\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\AVINAS~1.TRI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h2e_hkyb\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\avinash.tripathy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AVINAS~1.TRI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_qfc03y7\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\AVINAS~1.TRI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h2e_hkyb\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AVINAS~1.TRI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_qfc03y7\PyAudio\
```

Comment: It's building the code from source.  The error message says you need Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 and where to get it.  I tried a `--only-binary` option but it looks like it is only available from source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like PyAudio has a binary package available under pip. Christoph Gohlke maintains [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs) and it has [PyAudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio).  Download an appropriate version, then install it directly with `pip install`.