# Getting error code 1 while installing geopandas with pip

Tags: python, pip, geopandas

This is the error I get when trying to install geopandas using pip install geopandas. I'm using Python 3.7.

```
Collecting geopandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/11/d77c157c16909bd77557d00798b05a5b6615ed60acb5900fbe6a65d35e93/geopandas-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyproj (from geopandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/72/5c1888c4948a0c7b736d10e0f0f69966e7c0874a660222ed0a2c2c6daa9f/pyproj-1.9.5.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    using bundled proj4..
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 489, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
    IndexError: list index out of range

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\AVIMAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hnb_xdmp\pyproj\setup.py", line 72, in <module>
        objects = cc.compile(['nad2bin.c', 'src/pj_malloc.c'])
      File "c:\users\public\anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 345, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\public\anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 238, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
      File "c:\users\public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
        self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
      File "c:\users\public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
        self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
      File "c:\users\public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AVIMAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hnb_xdmp\pyproj\
```

I have already tried a bunch of other methods, like upgrading setuptools or downloading the Fiona and GDAL binary files, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 0):

As the Traceback says: Download this

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

This will give you the C++ libs required by the lib that you're installing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in compiling `pyproj`. Try to install a pre-compiled binary from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyproj

Answer (score 0):

[this helped me out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda)

```
pip install wheel
pip install pipwin

pipwin install numpy
pipwin install pandas
pipwin install shapely
pipwin install gdal
pipwin install fiona
pipwin install pyproj
pipwin install six
pipwin install rtree
pipwin install geopandas
```