# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. while installing pip install keplergl

Tags: python, kepler.gl

After installing shapely/gdal/fiona, I use `pip install keplergl` in jupyter notebook, the error shows

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\Anaconda\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hyq94\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bn96hrfp\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hyq94\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bn96hrfp\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\hyq94\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bn96hrfp\fiona\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried `conda remove gdal` and `conda install geopandas`, and uninstall and refresh package, but it doesn't work.

Is there any solution? Please help me with this problem : )

Comment: for Windows, add `--user` to the command

Answer (score 8):

When trying to install this I got the same error. My full error was:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gksasqz1\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gksasqz1\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gksasqz1\fiona\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gksasqz1\fiona\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Here if you look closely you can see the specific line:

```
A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
```

[Upon looking this up](https://www.bing.com/search?pc=COS2&ptag=D122617-N0640A21ABFDD9D88F4162B1F&form=CONBDF&conlogo=CT3332016&q=A%20GDAL%20API%20version%20must%20be%20specified.%20Provide%20a%20path%20to%20gdal-config%20using%20a%20GDAL_CONFIG%20environment%20variable%20or%20use%20a%20GDAL_VERSION%20environment%20variable.) I found [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda) which states that this error has something to do with [geopandas](https://pypi.org/project/geopandas/). Now the full response in my command prompt was:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install keplergl
Collecting keplergl
  Downloading keplergl-0.1.2.tar.gz (5.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.4 MB 1.6 MB/s
Collecting ipywidgets<8,>=7.0.0
  Downloading ipywidgets-7.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 121 kB 2.2 MB/s
Collecting traittypes>=0.2.1
  Downloading traittypes-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.6 kB)
Collecting geopandas>=0.5.0
  Downloading geopandas-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (928 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 928 kB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting pandas>=0.23.0
  Downloading pandas-1.0.3-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (7.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.6 MB 78 kB/s
Collecting Shapely>=1.6.4.post2
  Downloading Shapely-1.7.0-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (895 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 895 kB 544 kB/s
Collecting ipykernel>=4.5.1
  Downloading ipykernel-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (117 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 117 kB 2.2 MB/s
Collecting traitlets>=4.3.1
  Downloading traitlets-4.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 75 kB 1.2 MB/s
Collecting nbformat>=4.2.0
  Downloading nbformat-5.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (170 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 170 kB 3.2 MB/s
Collecting widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0
  Downloading widgetsnbextension-3.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.2 MB 364 kB/s
Collecting ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"
  Downloading ipython-7.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (780 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 780 kB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting fiona
  Downloading Fiona-1.8.13.post1.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.2 MB 1.1 MB/s
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gksasqz1\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gksasqz1\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gksasqz1\fiona\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gksasqz1\fiona\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

which shows that more than one item was required including geopandas as shown here:

```
Collecting geopandas>=0.5.0
  Downloading geopandas-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (928 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 928 kB 3.3 MB/s
```

If my assumption is correct then the error revolves around this area and so [the stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda) has some importance (based on a educational guess - could be entirely wrong here ). From the first answer to be shown (with 7 up-votes), that has been posted by @JDOaktown, you can see that there are more than one item required for geopandas. As stated in the answer:

> ```
> pip install wheels
> pip install pipwin
>
> pipwin install numpy
> pipwin install pandas
> pipwin install shapely
> pipwin install gdal
> pipwin install fiona
> pipwin install pyproj
> pipwin install six
> pipwin install rtree
> pipwin install geopandas
> ```
>
> [Source](http://geopandas.org/install.html#installation) [source](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels) [source](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). 
>   If you still have problems,
>   consider uninstalling the above (pip uninstall) and reinstalling.

You can see from here:

```
Collecting fiona
  Downloading Fiona-1.8.13.post1.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.2 MB 1.1 MB/s
```

that one of the items you are told to install is relevant. Not only that - it is before installing [Fiona](https://pypi.org/project/Fiona/) that the error occurs for me - it may be entirely different for you. This answer however does not help much as it is for installing geopandas only and stops before installing the target [keplergl](https://pypi.org/project/keplergl/). So if you keep going down you reach a post by @Josh Friedlander which has 13 up-votes. Here he states:

> Geospatial Data Abstraction Library (GDAL) is a library designed for
>   vector geospatial data formats. It's a prerequisite for installing
>   Fiona, the Python API for OGR (which doesn't really stand for
>   anything), which is in turn a prerequisite for Geopandas. On UNIX-like
>   systems the gdal-config script tells Fiona stuff about your particular
>   gdal installation.
>
> It seems that your gdal-config is not in one of the usual places on
>   your PATH, so Fiona was unable to find it.
>
> If you're using Anaconda, best is to remove gdal with conda remove
>   gdal and then do a fresh conda install geopandas.
>
> As a general rule, if you're using Conda you should never use pip to
>   install something inside it unless you're absolutely sure conda offers
>   no support for it. (Many package can be found on conda by specifying
>   the right channel - -c argument.) And specifically in the case of
>   geopandas, the maintainers recommend using conda over pip, since pip
>   requires you to install the dependencies correctly.

There are a few links so see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda) for them all. From here it is clear that conda is the way to go. After `pip` and `pipwin` installing all the components as instructed in the first answer I mentioned I went down to the Anaconda section (the second answer I have mention) and completed those steps. Now I have no more issues and the pip install works. If you still have issues then send me the error and I will have a look at it again. If the issues are the same then I cannot aid you any further. In the answer posted by @Pawan Upadhyay and then edited by @Bruno I found that I was getting:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\tom\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (46.1.3)
```

which means that it was not the issue for me. If it was for you then congrats on finding a shorter path than the one posted by me. Otherwise give this a try. I hope it was useful.
[Documentation for further reference](https://github.com/keplergl/kepler.gl/blob/master/docs/api-reference/overview.md).

Comment: How would I use pip win with a company certificate?

Answer (score 0):

it means your tools are not up to date

Can you try this in command prompt?

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25026403) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead