# Can not Install Geopandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, geopandas

Can not install geopandas with in python 3.7. Always this error pops up:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAENM.jpg)

[Problem in anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbM9l.jpg)
Please help!

Comment: Refer to this. [Error installing geopandas:“ A GDAL API version must be specified ” in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error installing geopandas:" A GDAL API version must be specified " in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda)

Comment: I wouldn't ever install geopandas and its dependencies into the base environment. IMO, you should keep `base` very clean and simple, and install everything in other, project-specific environments

Comment: I am also using 3.7 version and had same problem with you. What I did was update conda to version 22.9.0 using this command conda install -n base conda=22.9.0, then update geopandas using conda install -c conda-forge geopandas. Hope its ok for your case.

Answer (score 2):

First, based on [Geopandas](https://geopandas.org/install.html) documentations, they recommend to use [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) package manager.

Secondly, Geopandas relies on other packages and their installations is required. In order to install all the dependencies and the package itself, you can run the following command, given you are using `conda` package manager:

`conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried conda package manager but still not working. Not only geopadas, also fiona, gdal these packages are not installing. What can i do in this context?

Comment: Please update your question with the error you get when you run with conda.

Comment: @AhmedTahmidRaihan your Anaconda screenshot doesn't show any error, it only shows it is still "solving" the environment (=figuring out which packages need to be installed)

Comment: @Joris it does not solve at the end, it takes about an hour to run the solve and ultimately it does not install

Comment: Can you try to instructions in the installation docs to create an new environment and see if that works? https://geopandas.org/install.html#creating-a-new-environment

Comment: @joris, now the installation is working. Thanks a lot! :)