# Anaconda doesn't import geopandas

Tags: python, anaconda, gdal, geopandas, fiona

How do I make geopandas work?  I  have a new environment for geopandas. Before that I reinstalled anaconda. Pythom 3.8.5 is included  and no other python is installed. When I open jupiter notebook in the specific `geo_env` with the packages and `import geopandsa as gpd` it is not working - `missing package`. I know this topic for geopandas is quite well discussed but I tried all suggestions - different commands "`pip`"; `conda`; `conda-forge`; different versions of the files `gdal`, `diona`, `shapely` etc. (because it's written sometimes 32 bit works on 64 bit - my option).
I work with windows 10/64Bit

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try:

```
$ conda install -c anaconda pip
$ pip install geopandas
$ pip install Fiona
```

Comment: After I tried the Matt Cottrill suggestion unsuccessfully I stated with: 
conda install -c anaconda pip 
# All requested packages already installed;
pip install geopandas
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:  A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable

If you have further suggestions - will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

From [Error installing geopandas:" A GDAL API version must be specified " in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667). Your question has been answered well in this thread.

To install gdal, I followed the following steps:

downloaded the version that satisfies my computer (64 bit) from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) . The file was GDAL-3.1.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Put the file in a folder on the desktop.

From cmd, i moved to that directory and executed python -m pip install GDAL-3.1.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

This is followed by installing fiona the same way: python -m pip install Fiona-1.8.18-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

For shapely, i executed conda install -c conda-forge shapely

After that, i was able to install keplergl as usual: pip install keplergl

install descartes: conda install -c conda-forge descartes (or python -m pip install descartes).

In this way, i didn't have to play around with the 'Environmental Variables' as this may affect other programs Cheers..

Comment: First - many thanks for the support! Starting from (base env) in the prompt - with GDAL everything is fine but can't install fiona beacuse of - ERROR:  Building wheel for gdal (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-86_iw4xz\\gdal\\setup.py'"......