# Impossible to install geopandas

Tags: python, pip, conda, geopandas

I've tried all the installing methods in geopandas' [documentation](https://geopandas.org/getting_started/install.html) and nothing works.

`conda install geopandas` gives

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/win-32::__cuda==10.1=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 10.1
```

`conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas` gives the same error.

Created a new environment with conda:

```
Package python conflicts for:
python=3
geopandas -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=3.5|>=3.6|3.4.*|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
geopandas -> pandas[version='>=0.24'] -> python[version='>=3.7|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver: 

  - feature:/win-32::__cuda==10.1=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 10.1
```

I tried installing from source, no luck:

```
A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
```

I also followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58943939/13083530), which gives similar errors for all packages installing:

```
Package `geopandas` found in cache
Downloading package . . .
https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/z4tqcw5k/geopandas-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl
geopandas-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I also followed [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/geopandas-installation-the-easy-way-for-windows-31a666b3610f) and download 5 dependencies' binary wheels and pip install them. I have this error for installing `Fiona`, `geopandas`, `pyproj`

```
A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
```

I'm in my venv with Python 3.8.7 in Windows 10. I have GDAL installed and set `GDAL_DATA` and `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` as environment vars.

Comment: The docs say to use `conda install python=3 geopandas`, have you tried it with the `python=3`? Also from what I saw, this error has to do with your python version, so maybe you should try an older version (going from 3.7 to 3.8 seemed to be the most common reason for the error).

Comment: According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/KevinMusgrave/pytorch-metric-learning/issues/55) there seems to be serious issues with Python 3.8+ and CUDA-dependent packages. Using Python 3.7 seems to be the only reliable workaround.

Comment: you guys are right, downgrading to 3.7 works! thank you

Comment: See my answer on this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179706/installing-rtree-on-windows-64-bits/390568#390568

Comment: The comment by @duckboycool solved the problem in my case working on python 3.9. So, there is no need to downgrade to 3.7, just mentioning python=3 could do it.

Answer (score 3):

@duckboycool and @Ken Y-N are right, downgrading to Python 3.7 did the trick! Downgrading with conda `conda install python=3.7` and then `conda install geopandas`

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following works. I first tried conda install geopandas in the base environment, and that didn't work. Several times. I created a new environment in Anaconda Navigator, activated my new environment and repeated conda install geopandas, and tried installing geopandas from the Navigator and that failed too. Finally, I created a new environment using Anaconda Prompt and installed the package.

```
conda create --name pandamaps geopandas
```

See the conda>getting started>managing environments
https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an environment initially,
Then inside the new environment try to install Geopandas:

```
1- conda create -n geo_env
2- conda activate geo_env
3- conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
4- conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
5- conda install python=3 geopandas
```

and following video:
https://youtu.be/k-MWeAWEta8
https://geopandas.org/getting_started/install.html