# GeoJSON and MuliPolygon: shape polygon data into dataframe (python, shapely)

Tags: python, shapely, point-in-polygon

I have to find if the point belongs to an area. Information is given by geojson file.
I created DataFrame by:

```
choro = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'name':block['properties']['name'], 'area': shape(block['geometry'])}) for block in geojson['features']], ignore_index=True)
```

that code work with warning:

> *ShapelyDeprecationWarning: Iteration over multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms`
> property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry*

but works! btw, if you know how to modify the code to switch off that warning - much appreaite!

the dataframe looks like:

[image]

Here is the code for checking if point belong to the area:

```
for index, area in choro.iterrows():
    polygon = area['area']
    if polygon.contains(point):
        print('Point belongs to ',area['name'])
```

if I change my dataframe (exclude "shape" command) to get only coordinates (and no warning messages):

```
choro = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'name':block['properties']['name'], 'area': block['geometry']['coordinates']}) for block in geojson['features']], ignore_index=True)
```

I will have:

[image]

and obviously "shape" command for polygon:

```
polygon = shape(area['area'])
```

and:

```
polygon = MultiPolygon(area['area'])
```

are not working anymore.

The question is how I can get more clear code : to have polygons (or any other "working" structure) be stored in dataframe structure to work with shapely function to find if point is belong to the area and w/o any warnings or errors.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **geopandas** package to easily create your DataFrame like this:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import geojson
import pandas as pd
with open("FileName.geojson", encoding='UTF-8') as json_file:
    geojson = geojson.load(json_file)
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geojson["features"])
```

Then you create this function to return the polygon name for any point:

```py
def find_department(point):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.geometry.contains(point):
            return row['name']
```

To define the geo-point you can use:

```py
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point
point = Point(Longitude, latitude)
```

If you want to use **shapely**, I would like to till you that your code is working well without any errors or warnings but here is some of excepted mistakes:

1. You put your point coordinates in reverse order. Remember it is (Longitude, latitude)
2. The point and the geoJSON file May be not with the same coordinate reference system **(CRS)**. Please make sure to export your geoJSON file with the correct **EPSG** value which is: **WGS84 (EPSG: 4326)**
   Check [this PDF](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/sites/default/files/2020-04/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf) out for more details.

Comment: Thank you! I tried geopandas. unfortunately, it wasn't able to install them over Jupiter Notebook. But yes, will try to search new ideas by your replay.

Comment: To install geopandas use the cmd instead of jupyter and install it using conda as `conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas` You may need to install those packages first `conda install pandas fiona shapely pyproj rtree`

Comment: @OcMaRUS try this link for installing geopandas in anaconda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda