# How to set error installing geopandas package

Tags: python, geopandas

Could you help me understand why I'm having trouble installing the `geopandas` package?

See the error below:

[image]

Comment: recommended way is use **conda** https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error installing geopandas:" A GDAL API version must be specified " in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda)

Comment: there are lots of duplicate answers out there, but to clarify I highly recommend you follow Rob's advice and use conda.

Comment: I'm perennially frustrated with the various answers on this topic out there, so I just wrote up a mini guide to installing geopandas here - hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72251100/3888719