# Issues Installing Geopandas using Conda

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, conda-forge

I am trying to install the geopandas package for Python. I have tried every installation process outlined by Geopandas here (I have tried literally every option they offer): https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html. I finally thought I got it to work by creating a new environment (it appears the package is installed), however, when I try to import a shapefile I get an error. I have also searched through all the stack exchange answers on questions for downloading Geopandas and none of the solutions are working for me. See the code and error below. **Can anyone help me download geopandas successfully?**

I am running Python version 3.9.13, on Windows, using Spyder.

CODE:

```
import geopandas as gpd

# Set filepath
fp = "filepath.shp"

# Read file using gpd.read_file()
data = gpd.read_file(fp)
```

ERROR:

```
fp = "filepath.shp"

data = gpd.read_file(fp)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [3] in <cell line: 1>
    data = gpd.read_file(fp)

  File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:81 in read_file
    if hasattr(features.crs, "to_dict"):

  File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py:214 in crs
    self._crs = self.session.get_crs()

  File fiona/ogrext.pyx:634 in fiona.ogrext.Session.get_crs

  File fiona/_err.pyx:259 in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer

CPLE_OpenFailedError: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
```

Comment: The error explicitly says "CPLE_OpenFailedError: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files." Did you see if the install did download these files?

Comment: I found the gcs.csv file in the following path: C:\Users\myuserid\Anaconda3\Library\share\gdal. How would I get it to point to this location? @Parachute

Comment: when trying to do this with geopandas, this usually is a problem of conflicting base and env packages and dependencies. A clean install with miniconda (not anaconda) in a new env might help. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72251100/3888719.